# Displaying a conflict marker

Tags: javascript, iteration, vue.js

I'm displaying a conflict marker for each actor for each day, if the current day is in their conflicts:

```
<li v-for="date in next_three_months">
  <template v-for="actor in cast">
    <template v-for="conflict in actor.conflicts">
      <i v-if="date.datestamp==conflict.datestamp" class="is-conflict"></i>
    </template>
  </template>
</li>
```

This works, but it just feels like a lot of code (despite it already being a dozen or so lines shorter than how I was doing it before using Vue JS).

Here's my Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#schedule-builder',

  data: {

    cast: [
      {{ cast_list }}
          {
            actor: {
              id: "{{ actor_id }}",
              name: "{{ actor_name or 'TBD' }}",
            },
            conflicts: [
              {{ conflict_calendar }}
                { datestamp: "{{ value }}" },
              {{ /conflict_calendar }}
            ],
          },
      {{ /cast_list }}
    ],

    next_three_months: [
      {
        datestamp: '{{ now | format:Y-m-d }}',
      },
      {{ loop times="90" }}
        {
          datestamp: '{{ now | modify_date:+1 day | format:Y-m-d }}',
        },
      {{ /loop }}
    ],
```

Comment: Your Vue.js file does not appear to be written in JavaScript. What language or dialect is it written in?

Comment: It's Vue. Vue JS? See vuejs.org

Comment: It's a framework not a language and in the documentation the viewmodel is written in JavaScript. Your Vue.js is not JavaScript.

Comment: @danfo: are you rendering the JavaScript server side?

Comment: "This works, but it just feels like a lot of code" - do you mean just the HTML or the JS too? has the code changed since you posted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post has been around for too long and I don't want it to be [a zombie](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/120114) any longer... You haven't replied to our questions in comments but we see you have been on SE sites lately so I am going to go ahead with the code as is.

As [was pointed out in comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143034/displaying-a-conflict-marker#comment268222_143034) there appears to be some type of rendering (perhaps server-side) that is mixed in with the JavaScript code, which is not declared, so I wouldn't really be able to try running the code even if I wanted to :/ I could try to dig through your StackOverflow posts to find relevant code but I don't have time for that.

---

For the code you posted, it doesn't really seem like "*a lot*" but that depends on perspective... if you really wanted, you could abstract the code in the `v-if` (i.e. `v-if="date.datestamp==conflict.datestamp"`) to a method and call it instead of having the logic in the markup.

---

I question whether [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) is the best tag to use in the `for` loops...While there are no restrictions on permitted content within a `<template>` tag, it seems odd to have one nested inside the other. Would a simple `<div>` suffice for one or both?

Comment: I've since found a different way to tackle this, since you might can tell by my variable names that this was looping up to 180,000 times which wasn't very efficient. next 3 months (90 days) * every cast member (up to 100) * every cast member's conflicts (up to 20) = 90*100*20 = 180K.

Now I am using a `<dataset>` to capture each actor + their conflicts via `{{ actors }}<option value="{{ actor_name }}" data-conflicts="{{ conflicts }}{{ value }}+{{ /conflicts }}">{{ /actors }}`, then vanilla JS to put a tick mark for each conflict on the appropriate day.